# Emulating IRIX on a modern system

Tags: emulation, operating-system

Has there been any attempt to emulate a system that could run the IRIX operating system?

Comment: Unlikely, since (1) it was closed source software and (2) it was still supported on SGI hardware until 2013.

Comment: Have you done _any_ research? A web search?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. Most people just say it's not worth emulating it, or its too complex. I was just wondering if anyone here has seen something.

Comment: The closest you'll find is probably the [SPIM emulator](http://spimsimulator.sourceforge.net/) which emulates the MIPS CPU used in SGI systems.  Note that this emulator runs assembly language, *not* machine code.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/412588/156990

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is MIPS support in QEMU which can be used along with [SGI userland emulation](https://github.com/irixxxx/qemu) and an Irix disk image to emulate Irix under Linux.  The [qemu-irix-helpers](https://github.com/irixxxx/qemu-irix-helpers) may also be useful.